# How to chain several operators onFailure?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, quarkus, mutiny

I have a Mutiny reactive stream on an Uni where I want to implement the following behavior:

- Log something if an error happens;
- Retry five times;
- If the retries exhaust, log another message and recover with an ok value.

This is what I got:

```
someUni
  .onFailure().invoke(e -> log.info("Error {}", e.getMessage()))
  .onFailure().retry().withBackOff(Duration.ofMillis(100), Duration.ofSeconds(5)).atMost(5)
  .onFailure()
  .invoke(() -> log.info("Retries exhausted, Im going to give up."))
  .onFailure().recoverWithItem(Response.ok().build());
```

It does not look very neat, I had to call `onFailure()` every time I needed to chain a new operator. That's because `onFailure()` returns `UniOnFailure<T>`, but once you chain something else you're back with the regular `Uni<T>`. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the correct way to do what you describe.

`onFailure` is a group (not an operator) to define what to do upon failure, the Mutiny API was designed this way for readability purposes.

Comment: I get it. I thought there was a more streamlined way and I was doing it wrong, but it seems this is the way to go, indeed.